# Cannot find WORKDIR in the container

Tags: docker

I've been building nodejs applications and wanted to investigate projects inside a Docker container.
But when I check the running container via `bin/bash` I cannot find `/app` directory in a container

While building image no errors are being displayed

This is my docker image file

```
FROM node:15.7.0 as build-stage
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json /app/
RUN npm install
COPY ./ /app/
ARG configuration=production
RUN npm run build -- --output-path=./dist/out --configuration $configuration

FROM nginx:1.18
COPY --from=build-stage /app/dist/out/ /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY ./nginx-custom.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The /app directory is not inside of your docker image.
It's in your build stage image.
Check the /usr/share/nginx/html directory or don't use build stage.

Answer (score 8):

Sèdjro has the correct answer, but I wanted to expand on it briefly.

You're using what is called a [multi-stage build](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/). If you haven't seen them already, the linked docs are a good read.

Each `FROM ...` line in your Dockerfile starts a new build stage, and only the contents of the final stage are relevant to the generated Docker image.

Other stages in the file are available as sources of the `COPY --from=...` directive.

In other words, as soon as you add a second `FROM ...` line, as in...

```
FROM node:15.7.0 as build-stage
.
.
.
FROM nginx:1.18
```

...then the contents of the first stage are effectively discarded,
unless you explicitly copy them into the final image using `COPY --from=...`. Your `/app` directory only exists in the first stage, since you're copying it into a different location in the final stage.